# How can I restrict access to specific files on the server side in NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS 13 and would like to store some constants on the server side only. Specifically, I would like values in `constants.ts` to be accessible in `route.ts` files. I would like a separate `constants.ts` file to store constants used on the client side.

Is there a way to ensure that arbitrary files (e.g. `constants.ts` or `foo.ts`) are only accessible and loaded on the server side?

I believe one way to achieve this would be to use `.env.local` but I would like to reserve that file for API keys.

I read the docs for NextJS 13 but it's not clear to me how to ensure an arbitrary file like `foo.ts` is only accessible server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1.Create a folder named **server** at the root of your Next.js project.

2.Move the **constants.ts** file or any other files that should be server-side only into the **server** folder.

To access these server-only files in your **route.ts** files or any other server-side code, you can import them using a relative path.

```
import { MY_CONSTANT } from '../server/constants';
// Use MY_CONSTANT in your server-side code
```

NOTE: The **server** folder is just a convention, and you can name it differently if you prefer. The important thing is to place the server-only files in a separate directory that is not directly accessible from the client-side bundle.